# In C, how to pass a variable number of arguments (say, 50+) to a function which va_start() understands prior to calling vsnprintf()?

Tags: c, linux

**Question**

Is there a way to pass many arguments to MyPrint() below using some kind of array containing a list of pointers to strings that va_start() understands before calling [vsnprintf()](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-vsnprintf-in-c)?

Example of a format string specifier. It would be nice to create an array of the corresponding values and pass that to MyPrint() rather than individually passing each argument. I don't know if it's possible for va_start() to understand it. :(

```
"[0x%llX][%u] %s --- A=%llu (0x%llX)  B=%llu (0x%llX)  C=%llu (0x%llX)  X=%llu (0x%llX)  Y=%llu (0x%llX)  Z=%llu (0x%llX)"
```

**Details**

MyPrint() calls [vsnprintf()](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-vsnprintf-in-c) which prints a formatted list of arguments to a character array. The declaration for vsnprintf() is shown below:

```
int vsnprintf(char *arr, size_t len, const wchar_t *format, va_list args);
```

**Parameters**

- **arr:** Pointer to the character array where output is to be printed
- **len:** Maximum number of characters that can be written to the array
- **format:** Format in which the output will be printed
- **args:** Pointer to the list of arguments to be printed

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/p6d5canRM)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

int MyPrint(char* buffer, int bufferSize, const char *format, ...)
{
    int len = 0;
    va_list arguments;
    va_start(arguments, format);
    len = vsnprintf(buffer, bufferSize, format, arguments);
    va_end(arguments);
    return len;
}

int main()
{
    char buffer[256];
    MyPrint(buffer, 256, "%s %s","Hello","World");
    printf("%s",buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the existing code? `char buffer[40];
    MyPrint(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%s %s %s %d%s %s\n","Hello","World", "it's working", 100 , "%", "Truncate this text please");`

Comment: There are 50+ arguments, seems suspect to write a function with that many arguments.

Comment: @vengy Not just suspect, but almost certainly a bad idea.

Comment: So all of the 50+ arguments are strings? Then you don't need a variadic function; just pass an array of strings to a function that prints them. Perhaps we need to see a real example of what you want to do, not "Hello World".

Comment: You could change your function so that it appends to a fixed char buffer without overflowing it. You could then write your arguments sequentially, like you would do with `fprintf`. ([Demo](https://ideone.com/gV8DIf).)

Comment: Good thinking! I'll give that a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to pass many arguments to MyPrint() below using some kind of array containing a list of pointers to strings that va_start() understands before calling `vsnprintf()`?

The only defined ways to initialize a `va_list`, such as `vsnprintf()` requires as a parameter, are

- via the `va_start()` macro, operating in the context of a variadic function to form a `va_list` from the function's variadic arguments, and
- via the `va_copy()` macro, to make a copy of another `va_list`.

There is no mechanism in standard C to form a `va_list` from the elements of an array, except by passing them all, *individually*, to a variadic function.

Variadic functions are about coding flexibility, not data flexibility.  If you want a function that handles arrays of data, then write a (non-variadic) one that does so.

Whenever you consider writing your own varargs function, smack yourself in the head and repeat the mantra: "varargs is not the answer".  Only if you still have varargs in your head after a few iterations of that should you should consider actually investigating that option.

Comment: Nice tip: "varargs is not the answer". I'll try a different approach. Thanks.